# How to get the last value from the url in OIC?

Tags: oracle-integration-cloud

How to get the last value from the url in OIC?

```
https://test.com:111/fscm/resources/11.13.18.05/invoices/11111/child/invoiceInstallments/
00030000000SDSDD00057708000000000000CB2F0000000SDSC000577080
```

I want to get 00030000000SDSDD00057708000000000000CB2F0000000SDSC000577080 value from the url. Which is invoiceInstallmentUniqId. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to use regular expression:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test(col) as
  2    (select 'https://test.com:111/fscm/resources/11.13.18.05/invoices/11111/child/invoiceInstallments/00030000000SDSDD00057708000000000000CB2F0000000SDSC000577080' from dual)
```

Query:

```
  3    select regexp_substr(col, '\w+$') result
  4    from test;

RESULT
------------------------------------------------------------
00030000000SDSDD00057708000000000000CB2F0000000SDSC000577080

SQL>
```

Comment: how do I use this expression in oic?